# react-select how do I remove the blue box around the cursor?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When I focus on the input a blue box appears around the cursor. I'd rather not have this. I inspected the elements that the  component spawns, but couldn't find it[image]

Comment: can you share you code in sandbox, I can't reproduce this issue

Comment: any success on this issue?